# Angular change detection runs unexpectedly, based on the expressions order in the view

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection, zone.js, ngzone

I am just playing with Angular change detection cycle and I found something that I can't understand.

We have following component's view:

```
<!-- ver:1 call() was called 3 times -->
<div>
  <p>call(); {{ call() }}</p>
  Name obtained from the API: <b>{{ data.name }}</b>
</div>

<!-- ver:2 call() was called just once -->
<div>
  Name obtained from the API: <b>{{ data.name }}</b>
  <p>call(); {{ call() }}</p>
</div>
```

So in the ver:1 call() is executed 3 times,
we have such order:
1.call() method, 2.render name from the API.

In the ver:2 call() is executed just once
and we have such order:
1.render name from the API, 2.call() method.

I think the 'effect' comes from the forked version of the zone.js in the Angular, but
I didn't find anything that can explain such behavior in the Angular repo.

[Link to the example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-htmrfq)

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the line `<b>{{ data.name }}</b>` because `data` is undefined.

The 2nd version line `<p>call(); {{ call() }}</p>` is not executed till the `data` is available, when `data` gets assigned there are no errors so all the lines in the template get rendered. So it is called only once.

The 1st ver is called multiple times because `<p>call(); {{ call() }}</p>` is above the error line and gets executed every time there is a change in the `data` variable or there is a template error.

- The 1st time the method is called on rendering the template for the
  1st time and it encounters an error at the above line.
- The 2nd time, change detection runs when the error occurs in the template (not sure why change detection runs an extra time when there is a template error).
- The 3rd time is when the API response is available, `data` is available, and the complete template is rendered again without any errors.